# How to make Bootstrap "table-bordered" Fixed header and Scroll body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-tables

I'm trying to make the table header fixed and scroll the body and I have used the below CSS. But this will break table layout. (width of header columns are different from width of body columns). How Can I avoid this problem ?

```
#tblLocations thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}

#tblLocations tbody{   
   max-height: 290px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this == > https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/oVlgM

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this as an example: Fixed table and Scrollable body

```css
.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.tableFixHead table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th,
.tableFixHead td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.tableFixHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
    <div class="tableFixHead">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Content</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
           
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
           
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Nisarg's answer, just a slight addition in order to stop letting the body scroll over the header. In my case, the body was overlapping with the header, and adding the last css, solved the problem.

```css
.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.tableFixHead table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th,
.tableFixHead td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.tableFixHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

.tableFixHead tbody tr{
   position: inherit;
}
```

```html
    <div class="tableFixHead">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Content</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
           
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            
              <td>Smith</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
           
              <td>Jackson</td>
              <td>94</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```